# Numbering Item on Hierarchical List C#

Tags: c#, recursion, tree, hierarchical

I have a hierarchical list of type `Element`. Each `Element` has a `ParentElement` and a Collection of `ChildElements`.

I have written a recursive HTML helper to loop through the hierarchical list and print out each Element into a table row. I want to be able to label each of the Elements in the table based on their position in the hierarchical list. For example

[image: Example List]

Substructure has no child elements

Superstructure has 3 `ChildElements` - Upper Floors, Frame and Roof

Upper Floors and Frame have no child elements

Roof has 2 `ChildElements` - Roof Coverings and Roof Structure

I have the following HTML on a view that calls the recursive helper.

```
<table class="table table-bordered">
     <thead>
         <tr>
             <td>Reference</td>
             <td>Name</td>
         </tr>
     </thead>
     <tbody>
         @ShowTreeTable(Model.Elements, 1)
     </tbody>
</table>
```

The recursive helper is as follows.

```
@helper ShowTreeTable(List<Entities.Entities.Element> elements, int level)
{
    for (int i = 0; i < elements.Count(); i++)
    {
        <tr>
            <td>@level</td>
            <td>@elements[i].Name</td>
        </tr>

        if (elements[i].ChildElements.Any())
        {
            @ShowTreeTable(elements[i].ChildElements.ToList(), level + 1)
        }
    }
}
```

I had a more elaborate helper while trying to do this but it wasn't close so I stripped it back to this.

With the current example the results are coming out like so.

[image: Current Example Results]

Comment: So what are the results?

Comment: Dangit, that is like the 3rd Post in a row where the poster is not telling us what is happening or not happening. Aka what they want help on.

Comment: @Christopher "I want to be able to label each of the Elements in the table based on their position in the hierarchical list. For example (proceeds to provide image of exactly what I want)

Comment: @J.vanLangen I've added an image of what the current results are based on the provided example code.

Comment: @BadDub: The problem is taht each itteration, you are creating another table row rather then adding to the existing one. Just look at the HTML you end up emitting to see how wrong your code is. The plumbing tags must be unique.

Comment: @Christopher I know this is wrong and I know why I'm getting what I'm getting based on the example code. I've tried other elaborate variations of this (like I said in the OP) but couldnt get anywhere with them so I stripped it back to this. I know tags must be unique and thats why I posted here, to get some help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got this working by manipulating the the tree in C# before it's put in the view.

First I got the root elements and set their reference property to their position in the list (+1).

```
var roots = this.Elements.Where(x => !x.ParentElementId.HasValue).ToList();

this.Elements.Where(x => !x.ParentElementId.HasValue).ToList()
    .ForEach(x => x.Reference = (roots.IndexOf(x) + 1).ToString());
```

I then wrote another recursive method to update all the child element references. The tricky part on this was to update the all the children parent element before they where given their own reference. If this wasn't done all the child elements contained a reference to a parent element that didn't have its updated reference.

```
private void ShowTree(List<Entities.Entities.Element> elements)
{
    for (int i = 0; i < elements.Count(); i++)
    {
        if (elements[i].ParentElementId.HasValue)
        {
            elements[i].Reference = $"{elements[i].ParentElement.Reference}.{i+1}";
        }

        if (elements[i].ChildElements.Any())
        {
            foreach (var child in elements[i].ChildElements)
            {
                 child.ParentElement = elements[i];
            }

            this.ShowTree(elements[i].ChildElements.ToList());
        }
    }
}
```

This combined with the HTML code in the OP resulted in the correct hierarchical references.

[image]